# Show last three digits of numeric column containing values of varying length and mask others

Tags: sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server 2016 I have a numeric column with values of varying lengths. I'd like to display the last three digits and mask the others.

EDIT: Can this be done just in the `SELECT` statement without going through the Dynamic Data Masking process (creating a table, setting permissions, etc.)?

For example:
`20639636
23155`

Returns:
`XXXXX636
XX155`

I used a version of @Alan Burstein's answer. Values less than three digits return NULL but that is not relevant for my needs.

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 123456123 AS N UNION
SELECT 12312 UNION
SELECT 1234  UNION
SELECT 333   UNION
SELECT 22
)
SELECT t.N
     , REPLICATE('X', LEN(t.N)-3) + RIGHT(t.N,3) AS N_MASKED
  FROM t
;

N           N_MASKED
22          NULL
333         333
1234        X234
12312       XX312
123456123   XXXXXX123
```

Comment: Have a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I'd do it:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @t TABLE (N BIGINT);
INSERT @t VALUES (12312),(3322),(123456123),(123456),(123);

-- Solution
SELECT
  Original = t.N, 
  [New]    = REPLICATE('X',l.L)+RIGHT(t.N,3)
FROM        @t AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEN(t.N)-3)) AS l(L)
WHERE       l.L > 0; -- Don't need to worry about strings shorter than 4
```

**Returns:**

```
Original             New
-------------------- ------------------
12312                XX312
3322                 X322
123456123            XXXXXX123
123456               XXX456
```

Comment: I prefer this approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the Dynamic Data Masking link that Yogesh put in the comments but I'm not sure it does what you want.

I think you should be able to do it this way (will return rows that have 3 characters also) :

```
create table test (SomeNumber int)
insert into test (SomeNumber) values (123)
insert into test (SomeNumber) values (1234)
insert into test (SomeNumber) values (1256634)
insert into test (SomeNumber) values (1233436634)

select RIGHT('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,SomeNumber), LEN(SomeNumber)-2,3),LEN(SomeNumber)) 
from test
```